Trying to find the name of a gang film
I saw a film about 10 years ago, can't for the life of me find it again though :(
It was made in the 1970's or 80's. Its about a gang leader who meets a girl and falls in love so he tries to leave the gang. Then the enemy gang kills his girlfriend, and unlike most other films at this point rather than going on a rampage he has a complete breakdown and spends all his time drinking etc. 
I remember it was extremely violent and graphic - the last fight scene was at a train yards from memory. I remember they showed a guys hand getting sliced open pretty bad with a knife.
Its a low - medium budget film as well.

Sounds like the low-budget Deadbeat At Dawn from 1988. From the IMDb recap:

After one too many encounters with The Spiders (a rival gang), The Ravens' leader's girlfriend tells him to quit the gang or it's Splitsville. He does so, but the leader of The Spiders is hellbent on revenge and arranges the murder of the girlfriend. That ticks off the boyfriend, who wreaks havoc with the two gangs, who have joined forces in order to pull off a security truck heist. 

And after his girlfriend's death (but before avenging her death), the protagonist sinks into a deep depression and drowns his sorrow in alcohol, like you've described. The trailer is available on Youtube, as is the entire movie, and the climax indeed takes place in a railyard.
